# Python regex split case insensitive in 2.6

Tags: python, regex

I have the following code that works in Python 2.7:

```
entry_regex = '(' + search_string + ')'
entry_split = re.split(entry_regex, row, 1, re.IGNORECASE)
```

I need to make it work in Python 2.6 as well as in Python 2.7 and 2.6 re.split doesn't accept a flag (re.IGNORECASE) as forth parameter. Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can just add (?i) to the regular expression to make it case insensitive:

```
>>> import re
>>> reg = "(foo)(?i)"
>>> re.split(reg, "fOO1foo2FOO3")
['', 'fOO', '1', 'foo', '2', 'FOO', '3']
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a `re.RegexObject` using `re.compile()`  and then call it's `split()` method.

Example:

```
>>> re.compile('XYZ', re.IGNORECASE).split('fooxyzbar')
['foo', 'bar']
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, found it by myself, I can compile it to a Regex Object:

```
entry_regex = re.compile('(' + search_string + ')', re.IGNORECASE)
entry_split = entry_regex.split(row, 1)
```